# How to activate Office 2010 Beta

Tags: office-2010-beta

I downloaded Office 2010 Beta when it came out. I am now getting popups that I need to activate by tomorrow or it will be disabled. I don't remember ever getting any type of product key. What can I do to keep using Office 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same position here. You would have seen the product key on a web page after logging in to windows live (or whatever it's called), and before the actual download page. The page was mostly installation instructions with a product key at the top.

If you didn't bookmark, screenshot or copy it then you are almost certainly out of luck in a few days. Sorry.

Comment: can i reinstall the beta again at that point?

Comment: I suppose so, but maybe delete cookies/use a different computer/different browser as it might be "one per user". Haven't heard that the beta test has stopped, but they might have finished.

Comment: Actually, you can go back and get your product key still. Just go to https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/productkeys/off2010proplus/enus/ and sign in with your Windows Live ID, and it'll tell you the key they originally assigned to you.